# Getting ClassNotFoundException deserializing session attributes in tomcat clustered environment

Tags: java, tomcat, liferay, classloader, session-replication

I have a tomcat clustered environment with a Liferay 6.2 installation. Each tomcat have many Spring based portlet applications deployed. My problem is when the session replication proccess is running I get ClassNotFoundException related to custom classes of my portlets. Investigating this problem I found that it would be caused by the session replication proccess run in Tomcat core Classloader and my custom classes saved in session are loaded in custom portlets classloaders.

> Oct 07, 2016 1:42:08 PM org.apache.catalina.session.StoreBase processExpires
>   SEVERE: Session: EA336308A2FDB389CA636EDFC537BEB6.lfrtc1; 
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.pullmantur.portal.cruise.web.result.model.vo.CruiseSearchForm
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
>       at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:278)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.CustomObjectInputStream.resolveClass(CustomObjectInputStream.java:74)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1612)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1517)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
>       at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.readObject(StandardSession.java:1619)
>       at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.readObjectData(StandardSession.java:1084)
>       at org.apache.catalina.session.JDBCStore.load(JDBCStore.java:657)
>       at org.apache.catalina.session.StoreBase.processExpires(StoreBase.java:157)
>       at org.apache.catalina.session.PersistentManagerBase.processExpires(PersistentManagerBase.java:449)
>       at org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase.backgroundProcess(ManagerBase.java:566)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1352)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1546)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1556)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1556)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1524)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Can someone help me to fix this, please?

Answer (score 0):

If that's the case and session-replication is totally separated from your application classpath you would need to add your classes (those which couldn't be found by Tomcat) to Tomcat's Common classloader ([explained here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html)).

It's better to separate those classes into separate jars just with POJOs.

Otherwise, you could store you're objects as something more general (like a `HashMap`).